# Getting error on opening excel file from eclipse

Tags: eclipse, excel, eclipse-3.4

I am getting following error on

> Cannot create the in-place editor
>
> This is probably because there is no
>   OLE editor registered against the type
>   of file you were trying to open.
>   Failed to create Ole Client. result =
>   -2147417851

I have MS office 2007,and the excel file is stored as "save as 2003 version".

Answer (score 7):

I'm using 3.5 so things could be different. Window->Preferences->General->Editors->File Associations.

Add *.xls and add Associated Editor  (from this window you can select external programs to open with)

I think you *should* be able to open the excel file inside and eclipse editor, but it looks like the OLE is not working on your system for some reason.

Comment: Still getting the same errror.
It tries to open in excel and in the eclipse tab

Comment: I tried and although my co-worker can open excel files in a Eclipse tab, mine open externally in Excel.   This answer is incomplete as it doesn't cover why Excel doesn't show up as a internal editor when setting file associations for .csv and .xls.

Comment: Try my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54205617/cannot-open-excel-files-from-eclipse-sts

Answer (score 0):

first check the system editor available or not.
if available right click on xls file and click on open with system editor.
if not available follow bellow steps.

eclipse-->help-->Install new software-->search for editor and download and restart the eclipse. After restart the eclipse right click on xls file and click on open with system editor.

Answer (score 0):

Right Click on the file > select 'Open With' > select 'Other' > Click 'Internal editors' > and select 'Text editor' and Tick 'Use it for all *.csv file'

Note: You can select different editors to view the file.

Solution is for Eclipse only