# "Cannot create the in-place editor" error is occurring when I try to open excel file in "ods" format

Tags: java, excel, selenium

I am trying to manually open an excel file in eclipse where I have put various values to be used. However when i double click on excel file, it gives me error "Cannot create the in-place editor-This i probably beacuse there is no OLE editor registered." now i don't have any idea about this. I followed the steps given  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2847149/getting-error-on-opening-excel-file-from-eclipse). But it didn't resolved my issue.

Comment: your eclipse version ? can you try to reinstall and check ?

Comment: try this also :  Right click on the offending file.

and the  Choosing Open With -> Default Editor.

Comment: I am using eclipse oxygen

Comment: try to open with system editor . when you right click on excel sheet

Comment: Ankur it opened with "system editor", but before it used to open within the eclipse, So why it is not happening now?