# Cannot open excel files from Eclipse STS

Tags: excel, eclipse

I have eclipse STS 3.9.2 IDE. I imported a maven project with xls or microsoft excel files into the IDE. I figured out how to setup eclipse to open the excel files from here - [Getting error on opening excel file from eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2847149/getting-error-on-opening-excel-file-from-eclipse).

But, I get an error when I open the excel files from eclipse -
This action couldn't be performed because Office doesn't recognize the command it was given.

I could not find any answers for this online. How do I fix the error ?

**PS** - I have asked this question here also https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/Excel/Cannot-open-excel-files-from-Eclipse-STS/m-p/319710

Comment: You can save a XLS file as a .csv and then open it in Eclipse.   Asking a question about a bug in Eclipse is probably way off-topic for this forum.   I don't see any reason why it would even be useful when there are many other tools you can use to open XLS files.

Comment: @djangofan - I want to use excel to open xls files, without any conversion. In my question, I mentioned that I setup eclipse to launch xls files in excel. But, it is not working. I need to fix that. Btw, if you think that the downvote is unfair, then could you please nullify it by giving me an upvote ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had chosen the wrong excel "tool" in eclipse to open xls files. Here is the solution :

Eclipse > right click the xls file > open with > other > select "Microsoft Excel Binary Worksheet" > check "use it for all *.xls files" > ok.

Now the excel files will be opened directly from eclipse.